# Server takes 13 (!) minutes to boot when PCIe SATA card is plugged in

Tags: sata, pci-express

I've purchased a PCIe 4-port SATA card (model SA3004) on Amazon because I ran out of ports on a computer I'm using as a server (HP EliteDesk 800 G2, only has 3 ports OOTB). Currently, one drive is plugged to it and everything seems to work as expected.

The problem I'm encountering is that when the card is plugged in (in the PCIe slot), the PC is abnormally slow to boot:

- HP BIOS logo : a few seconds (normal)
- SATA card BIOS : 10-15 seconds
- back to HP BIOS logo : about 30 seconds (max 5 seconds without the card)
- black screen (!) : 13 minutes
- GRUB, OS, etc

The problem is 100% predictable and will disappear immediately after removing the card, and reappear after putting it back.

The I/O performances are normal when the PC has booted up, and everything else works well. Only the bootup phase is slow.

Some forums posts suggested entering the SATA card BIOS by pressing F8 or Ctrl+S while it's displayed on-screen, but when actually done the computer beeps and nothing happens.

I'm thinking about returning it and buying another one, but apart from this it's working really well and I'm not sure other models would fix the issue.

This is not an OS problem since the issue happens even without any drives plugged in. The motherboard BIOS is up to date. The CPU is an Intel Core i5-6500 @ 3.6 GHz, and 8 gigs of DDR4 RAM are installed.

Comment: If there is another PCIe slot available, move it to another one.

Comment: @Moab there are 2 slots, both give the same result. The card has the same behavior on another computer. It is obvious that the problem comes from the card, but I'm wondering whether there is anything that can be done on my side.

Comment: Sounds like it is defective to me. Try a different brand also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having run out of options, I noticed a switch on the card that had three choices:

- AHCI Boot
- No Boot
- IDE Boot

It was set on AHCI, and I knew that "No Boot" disabled the card, but I had not tried the "IDE Boot" option. I toggled the switch and started the server, and somehow the black screen went from 15 minutes to about 5 seconds, so I guess my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You've already identified the problem is the card.

Even if you could mitigate the issues the problem remains the card itself and you cannot trust hardware that does not operate properly.

The correct course of action is to replace the card itself.

Comment: For future reference: the problem wasn't the card. I've since replaced the card with a newer, more expensive card, that doesn't have the IDE/AHCI mode switch, and I'm back with the 15 min boot problem. The problem therefore lies with the motherboard, which I'll replace soon